# Local Notification after App killed using Alarm manager in android 10

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-broadcast, android-10.0

I want to show local notification on specific time. So that I am using alarm manager to set pending intent for specific time. But in my case Broadcast/Service is not getting called if application killed by user.

Check the below code and help me out why am not getting notification after application killed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        

        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this,MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (MainActivity.this, 1, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis()+30000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MyReceiver() {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
  
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyNewIntentService.class);
        context.startService(intent1);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyNewIntentService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        CommonUtil.showNotification(getApplicationContext());
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

  <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            />

        <service
            android:name=".MyNewIntentService"
            android:exported="false"
            />
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am also facing the same issue here. If you solved it please share the solution with us. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can check here for working sample of Alarm with Broadcast receiver.

[How to use Android AlarmManager in Fragment in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268402/how-to-use-android-alarmmanager-in-fragment-in-kotlin/64268667#64268667)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but this is not working for me after app got killed by user in android 10.

Comment: Are you using Emulator? If so, what phone? Also, try without the `Intent Service` that you're using. Ideally, try to completely replace your code with the solution I posted and see if it works. If it doesn't, problem is something else.