# WakefulBroadcastReceiver does not works when app is closed

Tags: android

Please help me out, a wakeful broadcast receiver is not called, I have set an Alarm with the help of Alarm Manager using **setExactAndAllowIdle()** with **RTC_WAKEUP** but still, my broadcast receiver not getting called when App is closed (means App is swiped from Recent Apps).
I am working on android 8.
Actually, I want to create an Alarm App that fires at the exact time which set, even if the App is closed or the device is locked.

Comment: check permission android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, also please provide source code

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to check out:

[Alarm manager is not working with long term tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303696/alarm-manager-is-not-working-with-long-term-tasks/64303940#64303940)

[How to use Android AlarmManager in Fragment in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268402/how-to-use-android-alarmmanager-in-fragment-in-kotlin/64268667#64268667)

All the information you need can be found in those topics.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` has been deprecated as of Android O and should generally not be used anymore. From the documentation:

> Deprecated: As of Android O, background check restrictions make this class no longer generally useful. (It is generally not safe to start a service from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to do so.) Instead, developers should use android.app.job.JobScheduler to schedule a job, and this does not require that the app hold a wake lock while doing so (the system will take care of holding a wake lock for the job).

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/legacy/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Comment: Thanks for telling me about this, so please can you recommend any approach I should follow to create a Strict Time-Based Event??